# Terraform Import Google Uptime Check fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, monitoring, terraform-provider-gcp, uptime

I'm trying to import an Uptime_check but keeps saying that the resource does not exist.

I'm using the follow command:

```
terraform import module.uptime_check.google_monitoring_uptime_check_config.default {{HTTP_GKE_Check_Backend_1}}
```

My structure is the follow:

```
├── main.tf
└── modules
    └── uptime_check
        └── uptime_check.tf
```

My resource is:

```
resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "default" {
  display_name = "HTTP_GKE_Check_Backend_1"
  project = "google-ABCD-012345"
}
```

My main.tf is:

```
module "uptime_check" {
  source        = ".//modules/uptime_check"
}
```

But every time I try I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "module.uptime_check.google_monitoring_uptime_check_config.default", the provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct   
│ and that it is associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
```

And of course the resource exists in the account.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

The {{name}} of the cloud resource is not just the name.

As per [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_uptime_check_config#example-usage---uptime-check-config-http:%7E:text=name%20%2D%20A%20unique%20resource%20name%20for%20this%20UptimeCheckConfig.%20The%20format%20is%20projects/%5BPROJECT_ID%5D/uptimeCheckConfigs/%5BUPTIME_CHECK_ID%5D.):

**A unique resource name for this UptimeCheckConfig. The format is projects/[PROJECT_ID]/uptimeCheckConfigs/[UPTIME_CHECK_ID].**

So, this command worked for me:

```
terraform import module.uptime_check.google_monitoring_uptime_check_config.default projects/google-ABCD-012345/uptimeCheckConfigs/http-gke-check-backend-1-ABCDE12345
```